# Is "'ve to" instead of "have to" correct?

Tags: verb-forms, contractions, semi-modals

I need your help. So, "have to" instead of "must" is correct, but can I abbreviate this with *'ve to*?

Is this a mistake, or can I use it so???

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/can-you-contract-the-main-verb-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [contraction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contraction) (A word or group of words resulting from shortening an original form) is tricky  as there are stressed words (for emphasis) in English.

For example, you usually stress "have" in "have to" and if you write "I've to go", you won't expect readers to stress "have". Therefore, it is not right to contract *have* to *'ve* when writing "have to" in English.

"Have" could be contracted when it is used as an auxiliary verb (I've been sick) and as a main verb (in British English) as the [linked question and answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-appropriate-to-use-short-form-of-have-ve-when-it-means-possession) indicate.

You can contract it when you write "I've got to go" as *'ve* is an auxiliary verb.

Answer (score 0):

Both, "must" and "have to" are used to express obligation, but "must" refers to a type of moral obligation. For example:

> My parents work a lot to pay for my studies, so I must study hard and not fail

shows you are **convinced**, whereas "have to" is kind of an imposed obligation. For example:

> We have to do a lot of homework on this weekend.

(we don't really feel it willingly, as if it were by force.)

The phrase "have to" behaves  as a principal verb and **cannot** be abbreviated,, but "have" (**without** being followed by "to") may be contracted when it is **an auxiliary**, that is to say, when it is followed by a past participle. Nevertheless, contractions (when possible), represent informality. They are used when speaking and in informal writing.