# Besides that, I’ve to mention;

Tags: tense

Dear All My teacher gave me a tasks to find a solution for this sentence.

He marked that the "I've to" part is wrong. But to be honest I don't know what is the resolution.

The original sentence part was that:

> Besides that, **I’ve to** mention; ......

Comment: Can you add more context — at least the full sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "'ve to" instead of "have to" correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88736/is-ve-to-instead-of-have-to-correct) (the answer is "no", it isn't correct)

Comment: @JamesK - that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I just (March 27 2021) heard a BBC Radio 4 announcer say "and now, we've an episode of..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `'ve` [to] instead of 'have' when discussing possession or ownership, or being obliged, instructed or required - e.g. 'I've a red hat', 'we've nothing to hide',  'you've to go to London for a meeting', 'they've to be there at eight' is not 'wrong'. It is a mainly UK usage, and may be somewhat old fashioned in England and maybe Wales, and is often an (upper) class marker. I saw it a lot in Enid Blyton books as a kid.

[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2018/05/i-have.html) discusses.

The usage may be less old fashioned and less class-marked in Scotland and Northern Ireland. This is how [Val McDermid](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/best-selling-crime-writer-val-mcdermid-673473) described talking to a librarian when she was a child:

> "My mum’s not well," I said. "I’ve to get her a book."

Of course you need to say 'have' in full if you wish to add emphasis, e.g. 'I *have* to do this'.

Comment: It's not all that old-fashioned. In the 1950s and early 60s my junior school teachers tried to get us to avoid 'got' - e.g. 'I've got a new coat', as being vulgar, common, and casual, but without much success, although it worked with me to some extent.

Comment: Dear Michael, really thanks for your answer, I enjoyed it.